# Trouble converting packed BGRA image buffer to RGB with OpenCV in Python

Tags: python, c++, image, opencv, numpy

Some context:
I have a [packed BGRA](http://www.fileformat.info/mirror/egff/ch09_02.htm) image in a buffer that I would like to convert to RGB.

I use the following code to convert it to RGB using OpenCV:

```
np_a = np.array( image_buffer ) #image_buffer is an array of uint8
rgb_a = cv2.cvtColor( image_buffer, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2RGB )
```

But:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in ipp_cvtColor,
file /home/username/opencv/opencv-3.1.0/modules/imgpro/src/color.cpp, line 7341
```

As OpenCV is open source, I have dived into the [source code](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp) to figure out what happened.

```
    static bool ipp_cvtColor( Mat &src, OutputArray _dst, int code, int dcn )
    {
    int stype = src.type();
    int scn = CV_MAT_CN(stype), depth = CV_MAT_DEPTH(stype);

    Mat dst;
    Size sz = src.size();

    switch( code )
    {
#if IPP_VERSION_X100 >= 700
        case CV_BGR2BGRA: case CV_RGB2BGRA: case CV_BGRA2BGR:
        case CV_RGBA2BGR: case CV_RGB2BGR: case CV_BGRA2RGBA:
            CV_Assert( scn == 3 || scn == 4 );
```

And:

```
#define CV_MAT_CN (flags) ((((flags) & CV_MAT_CN_MASK) >> CV_CN_SHIFT) + 1)
#define CV_MAT_CN_MASK ((CV_CN_MAX - 1) << CV_CN_SHIFT)
#define CV_CN_MAX 512
#define CV_CN_SHIFT 3
```

I am not sure to understand these lines of code.
I assume `scn` is the "source channel number" and that it is related to the number of dimension of the array. The assertion would then fail because the array was created as a 1D array.
Indeed, `print np_a.ndim` outputs `1` and `print np_a.shape` outputs `(422400,)`.

I tried many things. Among them, setting the array's shape manually with `np_a.shape = (image_height, image_width)`, which ends with this error:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000570558 in visit_decref ()
```

What am I missing?
Am I supposed to manually unpack the image before converting it? How?

---

**FIRST EDIT:**
The buffer is filled using a C API. It is supposed to be an array of UINT8.

Also, this:

```
print type( np_a )
print type( np_a[ 0 ] )
print np_a.shape
```

Outputs:

```
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
<type 'numpy.uint8'>
(422400,)
```

---

**SECOND EDIT:**

***The issue is already solved, this is only for a better understanding / another way.***

Using:

```
np_a           = np.array( image_buffer )
np_a_reshaped  = np_a.reshape( height, width, depth )
np_a_converted = np_a_reshaped[ ...,:3 ][ ...,::-1 ]
print len( np_a_converted )
```

Outputs: 480.

So yes, I was probably using `np_a.reshape( ... )` alone and assumed that it would change the shape of np_a. Why would you want to change the shape of the buffer ***and*** create a new variable?

However, the size of np_a_converted is still not correct. Indeed, later in the program, there is the following code:

```
img = wx.ImageFromBuffer( width, height, np_a_converted )
bmp = wx.Bitmap( img )
```

To create a wx.Bitmap from the buffer, without copy of the data.

From [wx.ImageFromBuffer's documentation](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/functions.html#ImageFromBuffer):

> The dataBuffer object is expected to contain a series of RGB bytes and
>   be width*height*3 bytes long.

And it gives this error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx/core.py", line 656, in ImageFromBuffer
img.SetDataBuffer(dataBuffer)
ValueError: Invalid data buffer size.
```

Comment: _Am I supposed to manually unpack the image before converting it?_ **Yes**. _How?_ No idea in Python... Sorry ;D However, the error says that you should pass a 4 channel OpenCV Mat to `cvtColor`, while your `np_a` is probably just 1 channel

Comment: I suppose you will have to create another numpy array with depth 4. Something like `np_a = np.array((height,width,4),  np.uint8)` and then manually fill it with your values.

Comment: It's an array of uint8.

Comment: What do you mean by a `packed RGBA`? How many bits per channel? 2-bit packed? 4-bit packed? 8-bit "packed"?

Comment: @Eric For now it's 8 bit per channel, but that amount will be a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to fix the issues:

- The segmentation fault was due to a wrong formula for the buffer size.
- I then used `np_a.shape = (image_height, image_width, image_depth)` to set the buffer structure to a 4 channels image (the assertion had failed because the buffer was read as an array of 1 dimension).

  Indeed, now, `print np_a.shape` outputs `(480, 640, 4)`.

  Somehow, `np_a.reshape( image_height, image_width, image_depth )` proposed by [Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37421379/5812729) does not work.

Comment: `np_a.reshape` returns a new value, without modifying `np_a`. Were you calling `np_a.reshape` then assuming the value of `np_a.shape` would change?

Answer (score 3):

If your buffer is 8-bit "packed", then all you're missing is a `reshape`:

```
image = image_buffer.reshape(height, width, 4)
rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2RGB)
```

It's not clear to me what `BGRA2RGB` does here - there's no "right" way to remove an alpha channel without choosing a background color. If the alpha data is garbage, you can go with the simpler

```
rgb = image[...,:3][...,::-1]
```

To ignore the alpha channel, and then flip the byte order. This is `O(w*h)` times faster than using opencv!

Note that if you plan to pass this array back to opencv, you might need to add:

```
rgb = np.copy(rgb)
```

Which makes the data contiguous in memory, a requirement of some opencv functions. This obviously loses you the efficiency gain mentioned above.

Comment: `[...,2:-1:-1]` is easier.

Comment: Well it's shorter, but I'd argue it's much harder to read, and the runtime cost is negligable as slices are views

Answer (score 0):

As you said that you are also using the C API, here is how you would do that in C++.

Let us assume that you have your BGRA data in 8 bit precision stored in a `uchar* buffer`.

Then all you have to do is cast this buffer to a `Vec4b*` like this :

```
Vec4b* new_buffer = (Vec4b*) buffer;
```

Then create your image like this:

```
cv::Mat image(height, width, CV_8UC4, new_buffer);
```

You can then apply the `cvtColor` function.

```
cv::cvtColor(image, destination, CV_BGRA2BGR) ;
```

**EDIT:**

Actually, you don't even need the cast. You can pass the data to the constructor directly:

```
cv::Mat image(height, width, CV_8UC4, buffer);
```

Comment: Would that even unpack it?

Comment: @DRz: in the case of 8-bit words, there is no "packing" anyway

Comment: If by packing you mean storing 4 8-bit values in a single 32-bit unsigned integer, you could do that with a cast too, I think. Something along the lines of `unsigned int* packed_buffer = (unsigned int*) buffer`. Of course, if you plan to use the values obtained like this, you should worry about [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).